# Microsoft Graph API edit chat messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am following the below document to update the Microsoft Team's chat message.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

As per the document, we can Only update the policyViolation property of a chatMessage can be updated.

It doesn't specify whether it is a post or get request.
I tried both via graph explorer.
GET return the message details and post return error "Requested API is not supported. Please check the path."

Does anybody know how to call this API via graph explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) it should be `PATCH`

[image]